# regular expression to get data out of a string

Tags: python, regex

I have a string `"["Newyork","Delhi","paris"]"` . I need to create a list of cities like this:

```
cities = ["Newyork","Delhi","paris"]
```

What would be the regular expression in python for it.I tried for few hours but could not get how to do it.could anyone help me in this?

Comment: Regular expressions are used to SEARCH for things; its not clear what (if anything) you are trying to search for here.

Comment: Take a look at Rik's answer. The string you have is already "ready" for parsing with `json` module, just like he shows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not something that should be done with regular expression.

Maybe you are looking for the [`json`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/json.html) module:

```
>>> import json
>>> json.loads('["Newyork","Delhi","paris"]')
['Newyork', 'Delhi', 'paris']
```

Answer (score 1):

And the obvious ast.literal_eval alternative is

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval('["Newyork","Delhi","paris"]')
['Newyork', 'Delhi', 'paris']
```

Answer (score 1):

How about a literal eval?

```
>>>import ast
>>>ast.literal_eval('["Newyork","Delhi","paris"]')
['Newyork', 'Delhi', 'paris']
```

The only catch is you'll need to replace those start and end quotes.

Comment: +1 for `ast`. But what do you mean by that replacement of quotes? `"abc"` is equivalent to `'abc'`.

Comment: Yes but look at the OP's string.  it's `'"["Newyork","Delhi","paris"]"'`

Comment: so, it's strip('"') before ast then, but I don't think he meant those quotes to be part of the string.

Answer (score -1):

you can use `eval()` which is a built in python function and doesn't require any modules:

```
>>> eval('["Newyork","Delhi","paris"]')
['Newyork', 'Delhi', 'paris']
```

Comment: fine until the you get a city called like this
`x"][0] and sys.exit() #`